# Controlling location of Pmw.MessageDialog (and other similar widgets)

Tags: python, pythonw

Python newbie here, newer still to Pmw:

I have the following method defined for showing a Pmw MessageDialog box, and it works as expected and the result value is returned and posted in edit1, which is a Tkinter.Text widget; 'self' here is a Tkinter.Frame. (running Win7-32 and Python v2.7.2):

```
def _showMessageBar(self):

        dialog = Pmw.MessageDialog(self, title = 'DBox',defaultbutton = 0,buttons('OK',Cancel'), message_text = 'DBox')
        dialog.iconname(dialog['title'])
        try:
            result = dialog.activate()
        finally:
            dialog.deactivate() 
        self.edit1.insert(END, result+ "\n")
```

The problem is, the call to dialog.activate() doesn't allow me to control the location of the messageBox.

If I change that call to:

```
result = dialog.activate(geometry = first+50+20)
```

then the messageBox widget is placed at the specified coordinates, *but this has two side effects:*

1) The messageBox widget now has the buttons of main window (close, minimize,maximize) rather than a dialog box (just the close 'X' button)

2) The result value is never posted to edit1.

**Question:** How do I control the location of the messageBox while maintaining the dialog box buttons/border and getting the value posted to the Text (edit1) widget.

TIA

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is that the geometry options need to be in quotes, I wasn't seeing the proper results because an exception was being thrown by the improper geometry specifier. This code:

```
result = dialog.activate(geometry = "first+50+20")
```

works fine.